# Cannot read property 'haDesignada' of undefined en recorrido de un for mas grande que el array

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando recorrer un array de objetos en javascript (reservas) dentro de un ciclo for (mas grande que el array) que imprime las filas de la tabla y a su vez deberia comparar si en ese array de objetos encuentra por la propiedad "hadesignada" y de ser asi pinte las columnas de otro color.

Dato: si modifico el valor de recorrido del for por el mismo o menor cantidad de elementos que el array funciona perfecto.

adjunto el codigo

Gracias !

ej array que quiero utilizar dentro de la iteracion:

```
var reservas = [   
            {
            "nombre" : "Ro",
            "apellido": "Gio",
            "check-in": "26/04/2020",
            "check-out": "30/04/2020",
            "tipoHabitacion": "Triple",
            "haDesignada": 8
            },
        {"nombre" : "Dan",
            "apellido": "guez",
            "check-in": "03/04/2020",
            "check-out": "06/04/2020",
            "tipoHabitacion": "Doble",
            "haDesignada": 1
        },
        {"nombre" : "Alex",
            "apellido": "R",
            "check-in": "15/04/2020",
            "check-out": "16/04/2020",
            "tipoHabitacion": "Doble",
            "haDesignada": 10
        }
        ];
```

Aqui el codigo:

```
var texto = document.getElementById("tabla");

textoloop = '<tr>';
for (i=1 ; i < 31 ; i++){
    textoloop+= '<th>' + String(i) + '</th>';
   
}
textoloop+='</tr>';

for (f = 1; f < 40; f++){
   
    if (reservas[f].haDesignada == 10){
        
        textoloop+='<tr>';
        )
        cont=1;
         while (cont < 31){
            
             if (devolverDias(reservas[f]["check-in"]) == cont){
             contaux =0;
             
             while (contaux < diasNroDiferencia(reservas[f]["check-in"], reservas[f]["check-out"])){
                textoloop+='<td style="background-color:blue">'+cont+'</td>';
                contaux++;
                cont++;
             }
             }
             // sino encuentra nada dejamos las celdas de color rojo
             else{
                textoloop+='<td style="background-color:red">'+cont+'</td>';
                cont ++;
             }
         }
        textoloop+='</tr>'; 

    } 
    else{
    textoloop+='<tr>';

    cont2=1;
     while (cont2 < 31){
         
         textoloop+='<td style="background-color:yellow">'+cont2+'</td>';
         cont2 ++;
     }
    textoloop+='</tr>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta esta en lo que pones como "Dato"; cuando quiere acceder a un elemento que no existe; tu lógica está mal. Si "reservas" tendrá distintos elementos (no siempre los mismos) te sugiero en vez de for (f = 1; f < 40; f++) pongas for (f = 1; f < reservas .length; f++)

Comment: Gracias @RobertoLeOr. Si, lo estaba pensado de esta manera: generar una vista (tabla) con habitaciones (filas) las cuales son la cantidad del ciclo (40) y columnas (dias) y que cada vez que encuntre dentro del array que tengo. que las ubique en las filas y cambie de color el estado.  Como entiendo que el ciclo quiere acceder a un elemento que no existe dentro del array intente solucionarlo con un condicional. Agradezco tu sugerencia y la voy probar.